# Is it acceptable to use conditional comments to block IE rather than UA sniffing?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-support, browser-detecting, conditional-comments

I just can't see a way to support IE8 and below.
Having said that, I don't want to sniff the user agent because it's bad practice and feature detection is a better alternative.

Would it be acceptable to wrap the entire content of my page in a conditional comment for IE9 and above therefore blocking IE legitimetelly? Or should I reconsider my plan?

Comment: IE8 is the most popular version of IE for my website (with 11 being a close second), I wouldn't drop support for it lightly at this point.

Comment: You'll probably want to mention\determine which features IE8 is missing that your site uses. Many missing features of older browsers have workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely relative aka, it all depends. I've never had a case where I decided to give up on an IE version. Are you building with web standards? and testing? what's the major issue(s)?

**A few thoughts**:

No it is never acceptable to shut down browsers and shut out users. Never do that.   Ok so you have to do it. Your plan to ice out < IE9 via cc is correct. Do that. Don't just serve up `display:none`.    Give the user an `explanation/context/link` to newer versions, other    browsers, etc.

**Segue rant:**

You are worried about best practices, so I have to point out that employing the best technical practices along with UX/UI practices is the way to go. Serving up nothing to a particular user is the worst thing you can do.

Comment: IE8 gets a banner, IE7 and IE6 get blocked. thanks for your help

Comment: ah. serve the banner up for the other two. if you need help, share the url.

Comment: tbf, when my site launches XP will be dead @albert

Comment: ah your missing the point(s). all hood.